# Displaying the value from the second hidden table when clicking on the first open table

Tags: javascript, html, sql, razor

I have 2 tables in HTML output. One is hidden. I want to use JavaScript to make it so that when I select a row with a value with the mouse, a window opens and the value from the second hidden table is shown. How can I do that?

View of open table

```
ID   Week_1 Week_2 Week_3 Week_4
1    1             3
2    3      1             1
3           2       
4    1             5
```

View of hidden table

```
ID Week_number  Value
1      1        1050
1      3        3024
1      3        5623
1      3        4560
...
4      1        4563
```

The code I use to select a cell.

```
    function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("duedate");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) 
            {
                return function() { 
                                        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                                        var id = cell.innerHTML;
                                        alert("id:" + id);
                                 };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}

    window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

How can I replace the selected id with other values from the hidden table?

Comment: You tagged this with razor, so I assume you're outputting the second table only to be able to access the data. Just output the actual data as JS const instead. That way you don't have to mess with <td>s and innerText again. As for getting the value from the second table: you need to use `let i` in your for loop, that way you should be able to use `i` and `id` to get the ID and Week_number. Now use both to read the value from the 2nd table's data.

Comment: You haven't even attempted yet to extract the value from the 2nd table, and it's not clear to me what your specific issue is.

Comment: `How can I replace the selected id with other values from the hidden table?`You mean you want to show the data of second hidden table which id is the selected row id?

Comment: Also note that another way is to do the lookup operation on the server-side and simply add the value to the first table's cells like `<td data-value="1050">`

Comment: @chris-g- Thank you, I am noob in Razor. You right, second table is hidden only because I need to take values from there. I have no idea how to do what are you writing.                     I have a dynamic values so I can't put it just in td data-value or Razor can do it?  
 
Yiyi You. Yeah. I have in the first table only number of actual issues per week, but I need to show what specific ID these issues have.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved partially the problem. This is the code.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("t-cell")).forEach((_el)=>{  _el.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        console.log(e.target.dataset)
        console.log(e.target.parentNode.dataset);
          
        let th = document.getElementById('t-hidden');
        let trs = th.querySelectorAll('tr[data-orgunit="'+e.target.parentNode.dataset.orgunit+'"]');
        console.log('trs : ', trs );
        let data = Array.from( trs ).filter((_el)=>  _el.dataset.week ===  e.target.dataset.week );
        console.log('data : ', data );
        let IDs = [];
        data.forEach(( _tr )=>{
            let td = _tr.querySelectorAll('td[data-rowid]')[0];
            console.log( ' td : ', td.dataset );
            IDs.push( td.dataset.rowid );
        })

        console.log( ' IDs : ', IDs );   
    });
    })    

});
```

Now I need to change values in the row by click or may be open modal window with the ID numbers. Any suggetions?

Update. Finally I did this with a modal window.

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
  <div id="myModalContent" class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Workflow items</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="modalLinks" class="modal-body"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
        ...
        console.log( ' IDs : ', IDs );  

        let content = document.getElementById('modalLinks');
        while (content.firstChild) {
            content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
        }
        IDs.forEach(function( _id ){
            let el = createLinkEl( _id );
            content.appendChild( el );
        })
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        modal.style.display = "block";
         
    });
    })    

});

function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("duedate");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) 
            {
                return function() {     
                                        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
                                        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
                                     
                                        span.onclick = function() {
                                        modal.style.display = "none";
                                        }
                                        window.onclick = function(event) {
                                        if (event.target == modal) {
                                            modal.style.display = "none";
                                        }
                                        }
                                 };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
```